# cuda unmet libraries but not going to be installed

Tags: nvidia, dpkg, cuda

I run into problems with `cuda/nvida` installation dependencies. Here's my `nvcc --version`

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

I'm effectively running cuda 9.0 and 10.1, in separate paths, no problems with the functioning of those versions. But problems arise when trying to do `sudo apt-get install <anything>`. I get `unmet dependencies` (particularly with libcublas) and get suggestions for `sudo apt-get install -f`.

I tried `sudo apt-get install -f` as suggested but errors boil down to:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-10-1-local-10.1.105-418.39/./libcublas-dev_10.1.0.105-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/stubs/libcublas.so', which is also in package nvidia-cuda-dev 7.5.18-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cuda-repo-10-1-local-10.1.105-418.39/./libcublas-dev_10.1.0.105-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can't run `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get install ANYHTING`.

I can't remove installations either.

The thread is similar to this one https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1048225/issues-after-installing-cuda-10-/?offset=5

But I can't solve it either by removing/purging.

Comment: Not really an answer, and perhaps that's the reason why no one answers formally: the link you refer to provides some commands to '"fix":     `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libcublas-dev_10.1.0.105-1_amd64.deb ; sudo apt-get -f install` . Not sure if this is clean, though.  Perhaps one should `apt install --reinstall nvidia-cuda-dev` or something.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon I ended up with several rounds of forcing complete removal and installing again...I guess it was nvidia causing trouble

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to:

1. Backup that file

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/stubs/libcublas.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/stubs/libcublas.so.backup_7.5.18
   ```
2. Then fix APT

   ```
   sudo apt install -f
   ```

Anyway, this is a packaging bug and better reported to the developer.